# Bash Automatic Exit/Log out the SSH Session

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that I want to launch upon a successful `SSH session`.

So far I have this working by placing the path to my script and the script name in the `.bash_profile` file.

The script that I have written is text menu driven with multiple choices for the user.

One of the options is `quit/exit`, which I need (once selected) to exit the script and log-out user from the SSH session.

Is this possible?

I've not been able achieve this as of yet.  Exiting the script is easy enough but no matter what I try I always end up with a command line prompt, which in this instance, we are trying to avoid.

Thanks In Advance,

Dan.

Comment: Use ssh-keys with a forced command, or investigate the `ForceCommand` option in the `sshd_config` file (that would be for all users though).

Comment: Stop on!  Thank you so much.  You can use the Match user option with this.  Great job!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Use ssh-keys with a forced command, or investigate the ForceCommand option in the sshd_config file (that would be for all users though). – Carlos Campderrós